# Change bitrate of MP4 file on OSX

Tags: video-conversion, mp4, quicktime, bitrate

I have to change the bitrate of MP4 files on Mac OS X. How can I do this conversion? Am I able to do it with QuickTime?

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is off topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *any* video encoding tool to change the bitrate of an existing video. The choice is yours – and on Mac OS X, you probably want to use one of these:

- [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)
- [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) (via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and `brew install ffmpeg`)
- [ffmpegX](https://www.ffmpegx.com/) (old version of FFmpeg with a GUI)

First things first: Re-encoding an already existing file *will* reduce its quality!  This is called [*Generation Loss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) and will affect any lossy material. Only re-encode the video if you really have to.

---

#### Encoding to another bitrate with Handbrake

Let's use Handbrake, since it's cross-platform and free *and* easy to use. Open up Handbrake, open the input video, then look at the *Video* settings.

[image]

Set the average bitrate to whatever bitrate you want to use. With h.264 codecs—depending on the resolution of the input video—you can choose anything between 500 and 2000 kBit/s, or even more. The setting will heavily influence the quality though!

---

#### *Intermission:* Do you really want to encode with average bitrate?

Also note that changing the bitrate to a fixed rate is not always beneficial for quality. Actually, if you want better quality for a certain file size, choose the *Constant Quality* setting instead of *Average Bitrate*, and use an RF (Rate Factor) from 19 to 24.

Here, you'll have to experiment what looks best, but setting a CRF will most likely give you a better quality. See [this guide](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/crf.html) if you want to know more about how the CRF works.

So, unless your scenario is video streaming, where you really need a fixed bitrate, you should probably use the CRF method instead.

---

#### Using QuickTime

It's definitely possible to re-encode a video with QuickTime. First of all, QuickTime Player makes your options rather limited. Open the video, go to *File » Save As…*, and tick the versions you want to export, e.g. "iPhone", which will give you around 1 Mbit/s bitrate.

If you have QuickTime Player 7, you have more options. Go to *File » Export*, then choose *Settings…* under *Video*.

[image]

Here, choose the H.264 codec, and restrict the *Data Rate* to whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I want to change the bitrate because I have to optimize videos for 3G or Wifi connexion (streaming contents)

Comment: Then that's the way to go! You're welcome :)